# What to do with the tag MAC

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag:mac seems to be used in [many different contexts in ITSec](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac)

- [MacOSX](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macosx)
- [MAC Address (networking)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-address)
- [Message authentication code (MAC)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-algorithm) [including HMAC, CMAC, and other constructions]

Since this has an overloaded meaning should we ban the creation of a new tag "MAC" (if possible) and create the tags MAC-Address and MAC-Hashcode ?  (The MacOSX already exists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm in favor of this. I might lean towards HMAC over MAC-Hashcode, though.

Comment: Agreed... but is there a way to make HMAC appear when a user types in "MAC"?

Comment: I don't think it would popup HMAC, but I would support HMAC in favour of MAC-hashcode, as I had never heard of MAC Hashcode before (only ever known it as HMAC)

Comment: HMAC is only one type of MAC algorithm; HMAC is a MAC which internally uses a hash function. Another widespread kind of MAC is CBC-MAC, built over a block cipher. There are various other proposals of MAC algorithms which are neither HMAC or CBC-MAC, too, but they are often integrated (e.g. GCM or EAX modes are encryption with a built-in MAC).

Comment: I think using the tag "HMAC" to represent message authentication codes would make us look ignorant about cryptography.  AES-CMAC is a message authentication code (MAC), but does not take the HMAC approach.

Comment: Surely, tag synonyms would solve the auto-suggestion problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create new tags, my suggestion would be to create a new tag [message-authentication-code](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-authentication-code) for message authentication codes (including HMAC, AES-CMAC, and others).

I do not think it makes sense to create a tag called "HMAC" or "MAC-Hashcode".  The correct name of the generic primitive is Message Authentication Code (MAC).   HMAC is just one way to build a Message Authentication Code.  Or, to put it another way: SHA1-HMAC is to Message Authentication Code as AES is to Block Cipher.

Comment: The tag "message-authentication-code" is above the 25 character maximum for SE.  What would you suggest be the shorter alternative?

Comment: perhaps MAC-algorithm?

Comment: @makerofthings7, ahh, thanks, I didn't know about that limit.  If it is over, then I recommend sticking with MAC.  I don't think there's much danger of confusion between MAC ("message authentication code") and MAC (the link-layer address); we could set up a tag wiki to clarify that we mean the former.